# Arduino multiple pin ADC read

Tags: arduino

Trying to read the value's from two analog sensors.
Can you use the for loop to read analog pins?

```cpp
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i = i + 1) {
  x[I]=(analogRead(A[i]);
```

Working Code:

```cpp
int AnalogpIn[2];
int MapValue[2];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
  AnalogpIn[0] = analogRead(A0);
  MapValue[0] = map(AnalogpIn[0], 0, 1023, 0, 255); 
  delay(100);
  AnalogpIn[1] = analogRead(A1);
  MapValue[1] = map(AnalogpIn[1], 0, 1023, 0, 255); 

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i = i + 1) {
    Serial.print(AnalogpIn[i]);
    Serial.print("-");
    Serial.print(MapValue[i]);
    Serial.println("");
    delay (100);
   }

}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,
I think this is what you are looking for. Have made few changes.

```
void loop(){ 
int i=0;     
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
 AnalogpIn[i] = analogRead(i);
 MapValue[i] = map(AnalogpIn[i], 0, 1023, 0, 255); 
 Serial.print(AnalogpIn[i]);
 Serial.print("-");
 Serial.print(MapValue[i]);
 Serial.println("");      
 } 
 delay (100);       
 }
```

Comment: while(!(ADCSRA & 0x10));

Comment: instead of the delay

Comment: why do you want delay?

Comment: just making sure that the pin read is done
before moving to the next pin read
analogread(0);
delay() - or - cheek flag()
analogread(1);

Comment: You don't need the delay, pin read will be done definitely. you can remove the delay from the for loop.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
     AnalogpIn[i] = analogRead(i);
     MapValue[i] = map(AnalogpIn[i], 0, 1023, 0, 255); 
     Serial.print(AnalogpIn[i]);
     Serial.print("-");
     Serial.print(MapValue[i]);
     Serial.println("");

      }    delay (100);
}

Comment: is there a way to attach an int i=0 count to call the int string
example - code not working

int AnalogPin[2];
int MapValue[2];
int i;
int str0[] = {0,1023,0,255};
int str1[] = {0,1000,0,200};

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    AnalogPin[i] = analogRead(i);
    MapValue[i] = map(AnalogPin[i], str[i][0], str[i][1], str[i][2], str[i][3]);